# redis-stack does not support environment variables for Redis Insight

Tags: docker, redis, redis-stack-server

I run a `regis-stack` deployment via docker.
See https://hub.docker.com/r/redis/redis-stack.

However, I want to host my Redis Insight (included in redis-stack) behind a proxy subpath.

I need to enable the proxy mode via `RIPROXYENABLE=true`.
However, if I set this environment variable for my `redis-stack` container, the Redis Insight part of it still is not in proxy mode ... as not mentioned in https://hub.docker.com/r/redis/redis-stack, are environment variables for Redis Insight not supported for `redis-stack` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RedisInsight v2 (bundled with Redis Stack) does not support the subpath proxy for now.
there are plans to do so, but it does not support it at the moment.